# Hibernate mapping without getter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to properties that are mapped to one column

```
 <class name="Account" table="list">

  ...

<property name="creationDate" type="jodaTime" column="accdatetm" insert="false" update="false"/>
<property name="anotherDate" type="jodaTime" column="accdatetm" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

`creationDate` have setter and getter in `Account` class

`anotherDate` haven't setter and getter in `Account` class

I got error

```
PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for anotherDate
```

What can I do if I don't want have getter and setter for property, but want have a property?

Comment: What's the point of having two properties for the same column in database? If it worked, both properties would always have the same value any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do if I don't want have getter and setter for property, but want have a property?

Change your mind, it is better to use a getter and setter for encapsulation and to maintain bean standards.

Comment: Clean Code says: Don't need accessor(getters, setters) if POJO has no behavior. This is called as data-structure class. But we can't use for entities because JPA implementators using proxies that works through accessors.

Comment: Hello @NimChimpsky, could you explain me some more detaily why my statement is incorrent?

Comment: @DanielHári its in my answer, your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact/display the database fields "createDate" or "anotherDate" in anyway you are going to need a getter. Hibernate assumes that you are going to use the property that you have declared, and its telling you that there is no supported way for you to use it without creating a getter. If you don't want to use the db field then don't include it as a property in the XML mappings. If this doesn't answer your question please give me some more detail on what you are trying to accomplish by referencing a field in a database that it doesn't sound like you want to use. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Hibernate allows you to specify field or property access. Check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping) but you can not mix for same entity. If you want to mix, implement your own `org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor` as specified in the link above. Probably you can start with `org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor` and delegate to `org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor` when no getter or setter found.

As other's suggested, it is much more simpler to follow one convention rather then going through all this but sometimes you can not avoid the crazy situations :)